# Configure qxt library under Windows

Tags: windows, qt, qt4, qt4.8, libqxt

I want to include into my Qt 4.8.1 project the Qxt 0.6.2 library.
I followed the steps from their user guide and at the end the library was installed in: C:\Qxt. I have added these two lines in my project .pro file:

```
CONFIG   += qxt
QXT      += core gui
```

and when i compile the following error appears:

```
error: cannot find -lQxtGuid
```

Also in C:\Qxt\doc no documentation was generated and the command assistant -addContentFile C:\libqxt\doc\html\qxt.dcf is not working nor the file qxt.dcf exists.

Edit 1: My problem was solved by selecting to use release libs from Qt compile options